# Maintain a file that exist in multiple repository

Tags: gradle, microservices, devops

We have **gradle.properties** that exist in 15 microservices repo. If we(devops) need to change a property, we need to go all through that microservices, commit changes and push. How to deal with this maintenance nightmare?

Note that the field in the gradle.properties are not configurations inside an application.properties or yaml that you can centralized with config server.

Comment: Who reads gradle.properties ? If your answer is spring or some java framework, is there a change to use config server or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar requirement in my company: for example settings our internal repository URL in a central place and not duplicate this URL in all `repositories {}` block from each project.

To implement this we have used the [Gardle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) feature together with [Init Script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script) feature:

- we have implemented an Init Script which is responsible to set some common properties (repo urls, etc...)
- we packaged a custom Gradle distribution that includes this init script in `GRADLE_HOME/init.d/` directory
- all our projects are configured to use the Gradle Wrapper with the `--gradle-distribution-url` pointing to our custom distribution .

Example of Init Script that sets one property:

**$GRADLE_HOME/init.d/init-properties.gradle**

```
 rootProject{ p ->
      p.ext.artifactoryUrl = 'https://mycompany.artifactory.com'
 }
```

*EDIT* : There is a sample project delivered with Gradle that explains how to build custom distribution: see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/customDistribution

Comment: changing `artifactoryUrl` value means redistributing the custom gradle wrapper to all the microservices?

Comment: You should be able to re-deliver only you main gradle distribution with updated url value: then  the gradle wrappers in each project should detect that a change was made in the distribution and re-download it. But I have never tested this: I think that gradle checks if the distribution archive is up-to-date, if not it will dowload it .

Comment: i just realized that we might have a design issue. We put clustername property on those gradle.properties, which the app should not be concern about under its scope. Anyway thanks for the help we can use this in the future ^^

Comment: I made a test in order to confirm the assumption I made in my previous comment:  in fact Gradle will not re-download the distribution if the distribution url (zip filename) does not change, even if zip file content is updated.. so in your case you would need to externalize the properties outside of the init script, and make this init script fetch updated values (for example from a file hosted on one of your companiy's repository)